# Obj-C/iOS: Setting delegations programmatically versus through the NIB

Tags: ios, objective-c, xib, delegation

Is there a difference between delegating in iOS like this:

```
 @interface JOLoginHomeVC : MCViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>
```

versus in the NIB, delegating each individual UI element by dragging it to the objects owner?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this:

```
@interface JOLoginHomeVC : MCViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>
```

Sets `JOLoginHomeVC` to conform to `UITextFieldDelegate` protocol.

Setting a delegate in `InterfaceBuilder` actually assigns the delegate.  It serves the same function as assigning it like:

```
someTextField.delegate = self;
```